# Netty TCP Server - Reject IPs before channel is created

Tags: java, networking, tcp, netty

So - I've created a TCP Server with Netty 4. The set up is simple, I'm using Netty's codecs to deal with serialisation.

I'm trying to filter based on IP address, it works but the channel is created and the handler is created. I dont want the handler to be created if its a filtered IP.

I add the filter in the server, here -

```
channelPipeline.addFirst(filter)
```

However my ServerHandler is always called first

```
channelPipeline.addLast(serverHandler)
```

The log:

```
Handler added - /127.0.0.1:58781 -- ServerHandler
2019-10-06 12:04:11.673 INFO - FILTER! - /127.0.0.1 -- Filter
```

I've tried to look for examples, but I'm finding it hard. I've also tried adding it in the same .addLast () Filter first with no joy.

TIA!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Norman for his answer, as perhaps I was looking in the wrong area. Our ELB on AWS has a healthchecker, which is hitting the Server 4 times a second, when a genuine client connects, it doesn't receive a message back. If I disable the health checker -it works perfectly.

Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use something like `iptables` to filter on the kernel level.

Comment: Thanks! I've slightly updated my answer - as I did find you said that to someone over at GitHub (I think my scenario may be a little niche...) Thanks mate for your contributions to Netty.